# Nhibernate dont update child

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

i have a Class Map CardMatch which have Employee and Card as reference
     Id(x => x.MatchId).GeneratedBy.Sequence("CARDMATCH_SEQ").Column("MATCHID");

```
 References(x => x.Employee).Column("EMPNO");
 References(x => x.Card).Column("CARDID").LazyLoad(Laziness.False).Cascade.SaveUpdate();
```

---

```
CardMatch _cm = _rep.getById(1);
_cm.Card.CardLimit = 500;
_rep.Update(_cm);
```

doesnt update the Child (Card). How can i update the Child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO your FNH mapping is correct. Flush method should be called on ISession instance. The last line is most likely redundand because NH tracks changes on its own.

```
CardMatch _cm = _rep.getById(1);
_cm.Card.CardLimit = 500;
_rep.Flush(); // save changes
```

Comment: i ve tried that. But doesnt work. NH never shows UPDATE() command in the logs while this code runs

Comment: which version of NH and FNH do you use?

Comment: newly upgraded from NH 3.0 to NH 3.1, and to FNH 1.2 ... Neither 3.0 nor 3.1 works.

Comment: Here is my code which makes update correctly: http://pastie.org/1755547. But I do not have access to Oracle database (or other db. that supports sequences), so the example is a little bit different from your case but I think it should not matter:). Please, are there any other differences from your case?

Comment: Thank You very much for your code Jakub.while comparing, I noticed that i have uncommented "ReadOnly();" in my map. Arrggh! it's been solved but i also have no hair on my head past 2 hours :)